# get All arrays from local storage in Angular

Tags: arrays, angular

I have dynamically created numbered arrays in local storage:

```
 key:   array1     value: [{foo, bar, etc}]
 key:   array2     value: [{bar, foo, etc}]
```

and I want to recursively pull all of them out. doesn't have to be fancy. I can't figure out how to do it. I have:

```
for (array of localStorage) {
       consolelog.(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(array)));}
```

but I know this isn't right.. local storage isn't even an array.
any ideas?
Not sure how to handle the fact that there could be any number of them, with any number in their name.

Comment: You can fetch all the values from localStorage, iterate on them one by one
`
for (var key in localStorage){
   console.log(localStorage.getItem(key)
}
`

Comment: hm. I think part of the issue is I'm creating them dynamically so I can't hardcode the names in a retrieve call. I'll make that clear.

Comment: Do you also need the array name or just the values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to iterate through the keys with [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and call [getItems()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_storage_getitem.asp) on each.

```
Object.keys(localStorage).forEach(data => 
{
  let item = localStorage.getItem(data);
  console.log(item); // item is the item from storage.
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can turn it into an array with `Object.values` method or `Object.entries`, depending on what you find more useful.

So it would be something like this:

```
for (array of Object.values(localStorage)) {
       console.log(array);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

store array in your local storage as an object

```
localStorage.setItem("array1", ["foo", "bar", "etc"])
```

And get the array elements like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
    console.log(localStorage.key(i), localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)));
}
```